# Use JPA's @Transient ist not visible in OData metadata

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, olingo

Just created my first JPA entity together with Olingo + JPA Processor. I want to use an entity
property with the *@Transient* annotation so the database is not populated with that value. Unfortunately
that property is not visible in the $metadata of the service. Is there any way to create
a visible property that is transient for JPA?

Answer (score 0):

For this reason, among others, it is discouraged to reuse your JPA entites (or business objects) as [data transfer objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object). Create dedicated DTOs and copy/map the data beween entities and DTOs as needed.